# What is the difference between access specifier protected and internal protected in C#

Tags: c#, access-specifier

What is the difference between access specifier `protected` and `internal protected` in C# ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does Protected Internal means in .Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651137/what-does-protected-internal-means-in-net) and [What is the difference between ‘protected’ and ‘protected internal’ ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585859/what-is-the-difference-between-protected-and-protected-internal)

Answer (score 10):

`Internal` can be seen within the assembly.

`Protected` can be seen by classes inheriting from the class where it is defined.

`Protected internal` can be seen within the assembly OR types derived from the class where it is defined (including types from other assemblies).

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx

Copied from the page:

```
public              Access is not restricted.
protected           Access is limited to the containing class or types derived from the containing class.
internal            Access is limited to the current assembly.
protected internal  Access is limited to the current assembly or types derived from the containing class.
private             Access is limited to the containing type.
```

Comment: What's the point of protected internal? Wouldn't protected on it's own do exactly the same thing?

Comment: @Vince, No, if it is `protected internal` and you derive from the class in another assembly, you would not have access to the method etc. But if it only was `protected` you would.

Comment: If I don't have access to the method in the other assembly, then I could simply mark it internal rather than protected internal. Am I missing something here? :)

Comment: @Vince Hmm yes, but then you would have access to the method without deriving from it.

Comment: you said "if it is protected internal and you derive from the class in another assembly, you would not have access to the method", however marking a method as internal in assembly A and deriving from that class in assembly B would give you same result would it not ?

Answer (score 2):

`protected` means only the current class and any classes deriving from it have access to the member.

`internal` means any class within the current assembly has access to the member.

`protected internal` essentially means `protected` **or** `internal`; i.e., all classes deriving from the current class (in any assembly) have access to the member, as do all classes in the current assembly. This is in contrast with what many developers expect -- that `protected internal` would mean the same thing as `protected` *and* `internal` (it doesn't).

Answer (score 2):

- `internal` - Visible by anything within the same assembly (.dll or .exe).
- `protected` - Visible by any sub-classes, no matter where they are.
- `internal protected` - Visible by anything within the same assembly *and* any sub-classes, no matter where they are.

The way Jeff Mattfield says "internal further reduces that visibility" makes it unclear. `internal` and `protected` are simply *different* visibilities. Having both together makes the member *more* visible. The default visibility of something with no explicit access modifiers, is as small as possible. Adding any access modifiers always increases the visibility.

Answer (score 1):

`internal protected` or `protected internal` which is the same means externally `protected` (from outside the current assembly) and internally `public` (from within the same assembly).

Answer (score 1):

**Protected internal** and **protected** access specifier relate to the concept of inheritance.

Let us take example to explain **protected** and **protected internal**.

There are two namespaces named **namespace A** and **namespace B**.

In **namespace A**, there is a class named **classA** which consists of a method named **accept()** using **protected** access specifier.

In **namespace B**, there is another class, named **classB**, which inherits from **classA** of **namespace A**.

Now with the help of this **protected** specifier we can access that **accept()** method in the **classB** of **namespace B**.

But that concept is not true when using the **protected internal** access specifier:
if **accept()** function of **classA** of **namespace A** was using **protected internal** access specifier, then **classB** of **namespace B** cannot access it because that **accept()** function can only be accessed within the inherited class within the same namespace.

Answer (score 1):

**- Update answer 2019 -**

Hi You can find accessibility via below table

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`internal protected` allows you to access members within the same assembly from classes which are not derived from the same object, but also allows the standard protected access you get for accessing the members from another assembly. It's internal | protected, not internal & protected (although the CLR allows the latter, C# does not)

Comment: From my understanding, protected internal makes no sense, protected internal is the same as protected and allows you to do exactly the same thing

Comment: @Vince - It allows the same access as protected, but **also** allows access from **non-derived** classes within the same assembly. (Which is not the same as protected). The difference only matters within the assembly it's used - in other assemblies where you reference that - it makes no difference to the programmer if it's protected or internal protected.

Answer (score 0):

To better Understand difference between protected and Protected Internal.it is better to first know what is difference between  Protected and internal.

Internal variable refer to same assembly.Yo can't access in different assembly.
protected variable like private variable but you can access in drived class in same assembly or diffrent assembly.

```
 namespace InternalTest   ----This namespace in assembly One
 {
    Public class A
    {
       B ol=new B();
        Console.WriteLine(ol.x);//Output:5  
        Console.WriteLine(ol.y);//error will occured. Because protected is like Private variable
    }

    public class B
     {
        Internal int x=5;
         Protected int y=5;

      }
 }
```

2)       Take diffrent assembly.

```
     using InternalTest;   
     namespace InternalTest1   ----This namespace in assembly Two
     {
       Public class A1:B
        {
           Public void GetInternalValue()
          {                     return x; //error can't access because this is internal

          }

          Public void GetProtectedValue()
          {
                return y;//Work because it's protected

          }
      }
       public class C
       {


       }

    }
```

from above example it clears you can access internal in same assembly but not in different assembly.You can say in same assembly it look likes public variable.you can assign value by creating object of class

3)protected internal have goodness of both in same assembly it look like public variable.
in diifrent assembly you use like protected variable

Answer (score -1):

**PROTECTED**

If the class is declared as "protected" means it can be accessed by the child class within the assembly as well as child class from outside the assembly.

**INTERNAL**

If the class is declared as "internal" means it can be accessed by any class within the assembly.

**PROTECTED INTERNAL**

If the class is declared as "protected internal" means it can be accessed within the assembly by their derived class only.